# c# grid view doesn't show results

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

In an aspx site I am getting data from a database and put it into a datasource, which then is used by the grid view to show the data. For some reason it works in the "facharztgruppen" grid view, but not the others. I dont know what I did differently.

Here's my code:

### C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Cockpit_RVI
{
    public partial class rx_check : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        String rz_id;
        String datenmonat;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rz_id = Request.QueryString["rzid"];
            datenmonat = Request.QueryString["datum"];
            if (rz_id != null && datenmonat != null)
            {
                update_sql();
            } else {
                popup("Bitte benutzen Sie das RVI Cockpit, um auf diese Seite zu gelangen.");
            }
        }

        protected void popup(String text)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "<script>alert('" + text.Replace("\n", " ") + "');</script>");
        }

        protected void update_sql()
        {
            update_facharztgruppen();
            update_liefergebiete();
            update_verschreibungsgebiete();
            lbl_rechenzentrum.Text = "ARZ " + rz_id;
            lbl_datenmonat.Text = datenmonat;
        }

        protected void update_verschreibungsgebiete()
        {
            ds_verschreibungsgebiete.SelectCommand = String.Format(@"working sql, tested in sqldeveloper");

            ds_verschreibungsgebiete.SelectParameters.Clear();
            ds_verschreibungsgebiete.SelectParameters.Add("datenmonat", datenmonat);
            ds_verschreibungsgebiete.SelectParameters.Add("rz_id", rz_id);
            gv_verschreibungsgebiete.DataSource = ds_verschreibungsgebiete;
            gv_verschreibungsgebiete.DataBind();
        }

        protected void update_liefergebiete()
        {
            ds_liefergebiete.SelectCommand = String.Format(@"working sql, tested in sqldeveloper");

            ds_liefergebiete.SelectParameters.Clear();
            ds_liefergebiete.SelectParameters.Add("datenmonat", datenmonat);
            ds_liefergebiete.SelectParameters.Add("rz_id", rz_id);
            gv_liefergebiete.DataSource = ds_liefergebiete;
            gv_liefergebiete.DataBind();
        }

        protected void update_facharztgruppen()
        {
            String jahr = datenmonat.Substring(0, 4);
            ds_facharztgruppen.SelectCommand = String.Format(@"working sql, tested in sqldeveloper");
            ds_facharztgruppen.SelectParameters.Clear();
            ds_facharztgruppen.SelectParameters.Add("datenmonat", datenmonat);
            ds_facharztgruppen.SelectParameters.Add("rz_id", rz_id);
            gv_facharztgruppen.DataSource = ds_facharztgruppen;
            gv_facharztgruppen.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

### site.aspx

```aspx
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="rx_check.aspx.cs" Inherits="Cockpit_RVI.rx_check" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div align="center">
        ...
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div align="center">

        <asp:Label ID="lbl_facharztgruppen" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: x-large" Text="Facharztgruppen"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="gv_facharztgruppen" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="fg" HeaderText="FGID" NullDisplayText="-" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="fachgruppe_name" HeaderText="Fachgruppe" NullDisplayText="-" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="anzahl" HeaderText="Anzahl der  Rezepte akt. Monat" NullDisplayText="-" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="b_anzahl" HeaderText="Anzahl Rezepte Vormonat" NullDisplayText="-" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="c_anzahl" HeaderText="Anzahl Rezepte Durchschnitt" NullDisplayText="-" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="aktuell" HeaderText="Dummy C Akt. Monat" NullDisplayText="-" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="vormonat" HeaderText="Dummy C Vormonat" NullDisplayText="-" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="mittelwert" HeaderText="Dummy C Mittelwert" NullDisplayText="-" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="Gray" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds_facharztgruppen" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ORADB_VAL %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ORADB_VAL.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="select 1 from dual"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" style="font-weight: 700" Text="not done" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnup_facharztgruppen" runat="server" Text="↑" Width="80px" />
        <br />
        <br />

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_liefergebiete" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: x-large" Text="Liefergebiete"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="gv_liefergebiete" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gv_liefergebiete_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="KV" HeaderText="KV-Region" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ANZAHL" HeaderText="Anteil Rezepte akt. Monat" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="B_ANZAHL" HeaderText="Anteil Rezepte Vormonat" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="C_ANZAHL" HeaderText="Anteil Rezepte Durchschnitt" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds_liefergebiete" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ORADB_VAL %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ORADB_VAL.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="select 1 from dual
"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnup_liefergebiete" runat="server" Text="↑" Width="80px" />
        <br />
        <br />

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_verschreibungsgebiete" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: x-large" Text="Verschreibungsgebiete"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="gv_verschreibungsgebiete" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="kv" HeaderText="KV-Region" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="anzahl" HeaderText="Anteil Rezepte akt. Monat" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="b_anzahl" HeaderText="Anteil Rezepte Vormonat" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="c_anzahl" HeaderText="Anteil Rezepte Durchschnitt" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="Gray" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds_verschreibungsgebiete" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ORADB_VAL %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ORADB_VAL.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="select 1 from dual"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnup_verschreibungsgebiete" runat="server" Text="↑" Width="80px" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Check your database record?

Comment: You are using `SelectCommand` `@"working sql, tested in sqldeveloper")` is this right ?

Comment: @Satindersingh no erros, the grid view is just not visible on the page, as if the data source holds no data

Comment: @Satindersingh I don't think that I need another way to populate my gridview, it works for the "facharztgruppen" GV, but not the others. I'm just puzzeled as to why the others won't work

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues. I tested this out a bit and it seemed to work fine for me. That leads me to believe it is a data issue. I know you said you ran the SQL and it returns data, but I would just make sure the SqlDataSource is actually returning data as well, and specifically, data with the columns you have in your GridView. Right before you bind the data, you can see what the SqlDataSource will return by calling its `Select()` method. `DataView view = (DataView)ds_facharztgruppen.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);`.